# stat_smooth in ggplot2 draws edges

Tags: ggplot2, regression, rounding, edges

I'm trying to draw a regression polynomial with `stat_smooth()` and get a not-so-smooth plot.

```
ggplot(AHorizontKat, aes(Kategorie, Solidago))+
geom_point()+
stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,3), se=FALSE, size = 0.1)+
xlab("A-Horizont in cm")+
ylab("Mittelwert Fläche in m²")+
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1 bis 3", "4 bis 6", "7 bis 9", ">10"))
```

[image: MyPlot]

data:

```
Kategorie <- c(1,2,3,4)
Solidago <- c(20.5, 24.6, 29.9, 352.9)
```

How can I get a more rounded polynom?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, it looks pretty smooth. You could change the order in `poly`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
AHorizontKat <- data.frame(Kategorie = c(1,2,3,4) ,
                           Solidago = c(20.5, 24.6, 29.9, 352.9))
ggplot(AHorizontKat, aes(Kategorie, Solidago))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,3), se=FALSE, size = 0.1)+
  xlab("A-Horizont in cm")+
  ylab("Mittelwert Fläche in m²")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1 bis 3", "4 bis 6", "7 bis 9", ">10"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your answer! For me the only solution was to create the df by myself (with c()) it never worked out with the original data